# hide url variables using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In my application the original file name for "pro" is profile.php and I have used htaccess to write it.

Now I have a URL which looks like this:
http://localhost/campuslife/pro?u=mchati.evelyn

for some reasons I want the URL to look like this

http://localhost/campuslife/pro/mchati.evelyn

Please how do i achieve this?

what I tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pro$ profile.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/campuslife/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pro$ profile.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^pro/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Not working for me...when I tried it all my css files, js files and img cannot load and it make my page scattered.

Comment: For css/js/images problem is not this rule but your use of relative paths. To fix you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: It works like a miracle!!! Thank you anubhava...best place to learn and to get help is STACKOVERFLOW!!!!